# Spring Boot - Consider defining a bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I receive the error when attempting to run my Spring Boot app:

> Field studentMapper in **com.adam.rest.client.impl.StudentClientImpl**
>   required a bean of type **'com.adam.rest.mapper.StudentMapper'** that
>   could not be found.

Could you suggest what is going wrong? (See files below)

**App.java**

```
package com.adam.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

**StudentClientImpl.java**

```
package com.adam.rest.client.impl;

import com.adam.rest.mapper.StudentMapper;
import com.adam.rest.model.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Repository
public class StudentClientImpl {

    @Autowired
    private StudentMapper studentMapper;

    private static Map<Integer, Student> students;
         // DUMMY DATA GOES HERE

    Collection<Student> getStudents() { return this.students.values(); }

    Student getStudent(Integer id) { return this.students.get(id); }

    ...
```

**StudentMapper.java**

```
package com.adam.rest.mapper;

import com.adam.rest.model.Student;

import java.util.Collection;

public interface StudentMapper {

    Collection<Student> getStudents();

    Student getStudent(Integer id);

    Student getStudent(String name);

    void updateStudent(Student student);

    void removeStudent(Integer id);

    void removeStudent(String name);

    void createStudent(Student student);

}
```

Comment: Aren't you suppose to implement `StudentMapper.java` in some `@Bean` implementation

Comment: Where is the implementation of your interface `StudentMapper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an implementation class for your interface:

```
public class StudentMapperImpl implements StudentMapper {
 ...
}
```

Then add a @Bean method to your [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) class or another @Configuration class.

For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public StudentMapperImpl studentMapper() {
        return new StudentMapperImpl ();
    }
}
```